# Error with the initialization of the array

Tags: c

I'm trying to initialize an array filling it with struct, and the syntax seems correct to me but the IDE I'm using keeps giving this error : `"[Error] expected expression before ']' token".`
This is my code:

```
    void caricaRegioni (Regione regioni[]){
    Regione abruzzo = {"Abruzzo", 65, "L'Aquila","Marco","Marsilio"};
    Regione basilicata = {"Basilicata", 77, "Potenza", "Vito", "Bardi"};
    Regione calabria = {"Calabria", 78,"Catanzaro","Jole", "Santelli" };
    Regione campania = {"Campania", 72, "Napoli", "Vincenzo", "De Luca"};
    Regione emilia = {"Emilia-Romagna", 45, "Bologna" "Stefano", "Bonaccini"};
    Regione friuli = {"Friuli-Venezia Giulia", 36, "Trieste", "Massimiliano", "Fedriga"};
    Regione lazio = {"Lazio", 62, "Roma", "Nicola", "Zingaretti"};
    Regione liguria = {"Liguria", 42,"Genova", "Giovanni", "Toti"};
    Regione lombardia = {"Lombardia", 25, "Milano", "Attilio", "Fontana"};
    Regione marche = {"Marche", 57, "Ancona", "Luca", "Ceriscioli"};
    Regione molise = {"Molise", 67, "Campobasso", "Donato", "Toma"};
    Regione piemonte = {"Piemonte", 21,"Torino", "Alberto", "Cirio"};
    Regione puglia = {"Puglia", 75, "Bari", "Michele", "Emiliano"};
    Regione sardegna = {"Sardegna", 88, "Cagliari", "Christian", "Solinas"};
    Regione sicilia = {"Sicilia", 82, "Palermo","Nello","Musumeci"};
    Regione toscana = {"Toscana", 52, "Firenze", "Enrico", "Rossi"};
    Regione trentino = {"Trentino-Alto Adige", 32, "Trento", "Arno", "Kompatscher" };
    Regione umbria = {"Umbria", 55, "Perugia", "Donatella", "Tesei"};
    Regione valle = {"Valle d'Aosta", 23, "Aosta", "Renzo", "Testolin"};
    Regione veneto = {"Veneto", 34, "Venezia", "Luca", "Zaia"};
    regioni[] = {abruzzo,basilicata,calabria,campania,emilia,friuli,lazio,liguria,lombardia,marche,
                    molise,piemonte,puglia,sardegna,sicilia,toscana,trentino,umbria,valle,veneto};
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, you cannot just reassign an existing array to new content like you did here. There are a few options how you could solve this but here are two possible solutions:

In the first one, since you already know how many regions you will be saving you can just access the existing indeces of  your array and re-assign each one to a new `Regione` struct individually.
Note: This is faster than the second approach, since you only acces each element once and reassign it.

```
void caricaRegioni (Regione regioni[20]) {
    regioni[0] = (Regione){"Abruzzo", 65, "L'Aquila","Marco","Marsilio"};
    regioni[1] = (Regione){"Basilicata", 77, "Potenza", "Vito", "Bardi"};
    regioni[2] = (Regione){"Calabria", 78,"Catanzaro","Jole", "Santelli" };
    regioni[3] = (Regione){"Campania", 72, "Napoli", "Vincenzo", "De Luca"};
    regioni[4] = (Regione){"Emilia-Romagna", 45, "Bologna" "Stefano", "Bonaccini"};
    regioni[5] = (Regione){"Friuli-Venezia Giulia", 36, "Trieste", "Massimiliano", "Fedriga"};
    regioni[6] = (Regione){"Lazio", 62, "Roma", "Nicola", "Zingaretti"};
    regioni[7] = (Regione){"Liguria", 42,"Genova", "Giovanni", "Toti"};
    regioni[8] = (Regione){"Lombardia", 25, "Milano", "Attilio", "Fontana"};
    regioni[9] = (Regione){"Marche", 57, "Ancona", "Luca", "Ceriscioli"};
    regioni[10] = (Regione){"Molise", 67, "Campobasso", "Donato", "Toma"};
    regioni[11] = (Regione){"Piemonte", 21,"Torino", "Alberto", "Cirio"};
    regioni[12] = (Regione){"Puglia", 75, "Bari", "Michele", "Emiliano"};
    regioni[13] = (Regione){"Sardegna", 88, "Cagliari", "Christian", "Solinas"};
    regioni[14] = (Regione){"Sicilia", 82, "Palermo","Nello","Musumeci"};
    regioni[15] = (Regione){"Toscana", 52, "Firenze", "Enrico", "Rossi"};
    regioni[16] = (Regione){"Trentino-Alto Adige", 32, "Trento", "Arno", "Kompatscher" };
    regioni[17] = (Regione){"Umbria", 55, "Perugia", "Donatella", "Tesei"};
    regioni[18] = (Regione){"Valle d'Aosta", 23, "Aosta", "Renzo", "Testolin"};
    regioni[19] = (Regione){"Veneto", 34, "Venezia", "Luca", "Zaia"};
}
```

In the second one you might want to create a new array like you wanted to do before and then copy this one to your already existing one.
**They have to be the same size or you will run into trouble**

```
void caricaRegioni (Regione regioni[20]) {
    Regione abruzzo = {"Abruzzo", 65, "L'Aquila","Marco","Marsilio"};
    Regione basilicata = {"Basilicata", 77, "Potenza", "Vito", "Bardi"};
    Regione calabria = {"Calabria", 78,"Catanzaro","Jole", "Santelli" };
    Regione campania = {"Campania", 72, "Napoli", "Vincenzo", "De Luca"};
    Regione emilia = {"Emilia-Romagna", 45, "Bologna" "Stefano", "Bonaccini"};
    Regione friuli = {"Friuli-Venezia Giulia", 36, "Trieste", "Massimiliano", "Fedriga"};
    Regione lazio = {"Lazio", 62, "Roma", "Nicola", "Zingaretti"};
    Regione liguria = {"Liguria", 42,"Genova", "Giovanni", "Toti"};
    Regione lombardia = {"Lombardia", 25, "Milano", "Attilio", "Fontana"};
    Regione marche = {"Marche", 57, "Ancona", "Luca", "Ceriscioli"};
    Regione molise = {"Molise", 67, "Campobasso", "Donato", "Toma"};
    Regione piemonte = {"Piemonte", 21,"Torino", "Alberto", "Cirio"};
    Regione puglia = {"Puglia", 75, "Bari", "Michele", "Emiliano"};
    Regione sardegna = {"Sardegna", 88, "Cagliari", "Christian", "Solinas"};
    Regione sicilia = {"Sicilia", 82, "Palermo","Nello","Musumeci"};
    Regione toscana = {"Toscana", 52, "Firenze", "Enrico", "Rossi"};
    Regione trentino = {"Trentino-Alto Adige", 32, "Trento", "Arno", "Kompatscher" };
    Regione umbria = {"Umbria", 55, "Perugia", "Donatella", "Tesei"};
    Regione valle = {"Valle d'Aosta", 23, "Aosta", "Renzo", "Testolin"};
    Regione veneto = {"Veneto", 34, "Venezia", "Luca", "Zaia"};

    Regione new_regions[20] = { abruzzo,basilicata,calabria,campania,emilia,friuli,lazio,liguria,lombardia,marche,
                                molise,piemonte,puglia,sardegna,sicilia,toscana,trentino,umbria,valle,veneto};

    memcpy(regioni, new_regions, sizeof(new_regions));
}
```

**I have also adjusted the parameter array to have a fixed size, since it would be really careless to just assume the size is going to be length x when its not.**

Comment: `regioni[0] = {"Abruzzo", 65, "L'Aquila","Marco","Marsilio"};` This will never compile.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, it was really explicative!

Comment: @KamilCuk You are right, sorry I wasn't paying attention :D I editted the first example

Comment: @GaetanoCrisafulli No. Do: `regioni[0] = (Regione){"Abruzzo", 65, "L'Aquila","Marco","Marsilio"};` [compound literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal)